# Minimum spanning tree of graph obtained by Prim's algorithm

Tags: graph, helper, minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I need some assistance on a Prim's algorithm problem:

Let T be a minimum spanning tree of graph G obtained by Prim's algorithm. Let Gnew be a graph obtained by adding to G a new vertex and some edges with weights, connecting the new vertex to some vertices in G. Can we construct a minimum spanning tree of Gnew by adding one of the new edges to T? If you answer yes, explain how; if no, explain why.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we construct a minimum spanning tree of Gnew by adding one of the
>   new edges to T?

No. Not in general. 
Assume `T` has been generated by considering verteices in order `v1,v2,...,vn-1`

Let `vn` be the new vertex and `(v1,vn)` be a weighted edge (v1 is the root of T), if the weight of `(v1,vn)` is smaller than the weight of `(v1,v2)` in T, this would not be MST anymore.

Answer (score 0):

not in all cases we can  add new edge  in T , it depends on the weight of new edges, because sometimes the old MST(T) will changes if the new  edges weight is small than other weight in graph

Answer (score 0):

No, this might be easier to visualize with a counter example:
[image: MST counter example]

as seen from above, not only is the new MST missing an edge compared to the original MST. It also uses both vertices instead of just one.